# Get locale reading direction (Android)

Tags: android, locale

My app receives from the server the list of the interface language codes the clients (iOS/Android/Web) can display.
So far a business requirement in our Android app is to filter out the RTL languages (Arabic, ...) and only keep the LTR languages (French, English, ...).

How can I get the locale reading direction?

I tried two methods I found but they return LTR for Arabic which isn't what I want (I don't even understand why it does return that to be honest):

```
val ar1 = Character.getDirectionality(Locale("ar-EG").getDisplayName().get(0))
val ar2 = TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale("ar-EG"))
// both returns 0 -> LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR -- Not what I expect

val en1 = Character.getDirectionality(Locale("en-GB").getDisplayName().get(0))
val en2 = TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale("en-GB"))
// both returns 0 -> LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR -- What I expect
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so... it happens that I was using this code in unit tests (wanted to try the approach "unit tests first"). The problem is that TextUtils need to be mocked, if you don't, the behavior as I was using it in a unit test isn't the expected one.

If you use this piece of code in the code of the app itself, it works as a charm.

Newbie to Android... beuheuheu...